# Recipe for upgrading JBoss 5.x Hibernate to 3.5.x?

Tags: hibernate, jboss5.x

I'd like to upgrade the Hibernate installation that ships as part of JBoss 5.1.x to Hibernate 3.5.x.

Is there an "approved" recipe for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible because of the [tight coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588108/hibernate-3-5-final-in-jboss-5-1-0-ga/2596603#2596603) of JBoss 5.1 with their JPA 1.0 implementation. And the fact that JBoss skipped JBoss 5.2 in favor of JBoss 6 suggest that they are not going to provide extensions points for Java EE 6 features in their Java EE 5 container.

Answer (score 0):

I have build a workaround for this specific issue. I explain all the details in another post : [How to use JPA2 on JBoss 5.x ? (or How to eliminate class loading isolation issue?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8476944/363573)