# How to get JPA 2.0 with JBoss 5.1?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I am reading Pro JPA 2 book and trying examples in it. I am using Eclipse Kepler and JBoss 5.1.0.

In eclipse I created a Dynamic Web Project with a JPA project facet. For the *JPA implementation Type* I selected *Disable Library Configuration* which means I will be using JBoss's Hibernate as JPA implementation library.

I got error on this line of code:

```
TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e", Employee.class);
```

These are the error messages:

> TypedQuery cannot be resolved to a type
>
> The method createQuery(String) in the type EntityManager is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, Class)

I believe `TypedQuery` was introduced in JPA 2.0 which means the JBoss 5.1 I have does not support JPA 2.0. Correct? So what I need to do so that I can use JPA 2.0 with JBoss 5.1?

Comment: Which error are you getting? Post the exact message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JBoss 5.1: Hibernate with JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140170/jboss-5-1-hibernate-with-jpa)

Comment: @mins I have updated the question to include the error messages

Comment: Are you using dependency management? I ran into this error message based on a classpath loading issue with the application server jar.