# Java EE Example not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

In this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html) we can see example of usage `@CollectioTable` annotation

I wrote the same code

```
@Entity public class Person {
       @ElementCollection
       @CollectionTable(name="HOMES", joinColumns = @Column(name = "PERSON_ID"))  
       @Column(name="HOME_STATE")
       protected List<String> vacationHomes;
       ...
    }
```

Usinf *Hibernate-jpa-2* version *1.0.0.Final*

Deploy on JBoss 4.3.0.GA

And get exception (while deploying), that `column HOME_STATE cann't be mapped on java.util.List`

so I change List to ArrayList

After that application was deployed well.
But doesn't work well! I execute simple query, but annotations `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable`  were ignored! Working only `@Column` annotation

Can be problem with old JBoss version?
I don't know where problem...

Comment: `java.utils.List` is a typo or a custom List class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Features that are part of JPA 2.0 are not working. That's because of missing implementation. In this case, only new annotations are there, but no processing (hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final is only JPA 2.0 interface, not the implementation).

According [releases notes](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=614346&group_id=22866) JBoss 4.3.0.GA was shipped with Hibernate 3.2.1, which is not JPA 2.0 implementation.

Making it work is next from impossible also with JBoss 5, as you can read from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476944/class-loading-isolation-issue-or-how-to-use-jpa2-on-jboss-5-x). If you cannot update at least to the JBoss 6.x, then it is easier to stick with JPA 1.

Comment: So bad.  '@ElementCollection' since JPA 2, but I am using JBoss 4.3.0.GA :-(

Comment: With hibernate xml mapping I cann't use Element-Collection too?

Comment: Same limitation is there. But if you are ready to discard JPA compatibility and use Hibernate specific solution, CollectionOfElements is likely answer. Looks like it is part of hibernate annotations 3.2.1: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.2.1.ga/hibernate-annotations-3.2.1.ga.jar!/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionOfElements.class?classDetails=ok